# How to compute the R-squared for a transformed response variable?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

Suppose that I run a linear regression

y = x*b + error,

and obtain predictions y_p. Furthermore, assume that I can compute the R-squared by calling a function R(y, y_p) which has two arguments: a vector of observations and a vector of predictions.

Now, I run the linear regression for a transformed response

ln(y) = x*b + error,

and obtain predictions  y_ln_p. How do I compute the R-squared for the sake of fair comparison with the previous model? Which one of the two would be better:

a) R(ln(y), y_ln_p)

b) R(y, e^y_ln_p)

Thank you!

NB: ln is the natural log.

Comment: I think that it might be feasible to migrate this question to _Cross Validated_ site, as it seems that the topic is focused purely on statistics.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/131182/36229

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is **not appropriate** to compare linear regression models in terms of their *summary/fit statistics* (RMSE and $R^2$), when some models' dependent variables were *transformed* so that units changed, as summary statistics are not comparable. Consider the following nice explanation by Maddala (1988, p. 177):

> When comparing the linear with the log-linear forms, we cannot compare
>   the R-squared's because R-squared is the ratio of explained variance
>   to the total variance and the variances of y and log y are different.
>   Comparing R-squared's in this case is like comparing two individuals,
>   A and B, where A eats 65% of a carrot cake and B eats 70% of a
>   strawberry cake. The comparison does not make sense because there are
>   two different cakes.

In order to compensate for the scale change, traditionally, people revert the log transformation back to the original scale by using so-called *back-transformation method* (see [this page](http://stattrek.com/regression/linear-transformation.aspx) for more details, explanation and examples).

In regard to the *information theory-based* model statistics, such as *AIC/BIC*, in general it is not possible to use them to compare non-transformed and transformed models (see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/76076/31372) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48723/31372). It is, however, possible to compare *AIC* with a modified *AIC* (not sure about *BIC*), as discussed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#Transforming_data) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100671/31372).

One additional - and the final - **note** is that it is usually preferred to use *adjusted $R^2$* instead of the standard one. Please see [my relevant answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/131217/31372) and links provided there.

**References**

Maddala, G. S. (1988). *Introduction to econometrics.* New York: Macmillan Publishing

Comment: Many thanks Aleksandr! I greatly appreciate your detailed answer. Bolshoe spasibo.

Comment: @user77571: You're very welcome. It is a pleasure and it was an educational experience for me as well. Ne za chto :-).